# How do I publish Gradle plugins to Artifactory?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I am working with this example Gradle Plugin project:
https://github.com/AlainODea/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin

When I run **./gradlew publishToMavenLocal** it creates these files in M2_HOME:

1. com/hello/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin/maven-metadata-local.xml
2. com/hello/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
3. com/hello/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-local.xml
4. com/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/maven-metadata-local.xml
5. com/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
6. com/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
7. com/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-local.xml

When I run **./gradlew artifactoryPublish** it logs:

```
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/com/example/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/com/example/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/webapp/builds/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/1234567890123
```

Attempting to load the plug-in from another build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.example.hello' version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

With settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/'
        }
    }
}
```

Results in this error:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.example', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.example.hello:com.example.hello.gradle.plugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

I'd like to get all of the artifacts that publishToMavenLocal creates to be published to Artifactory when I run artifactoryPublish. I am open to alternatives to artifactoryPublish if it is the wrong tool.

How do I publish Gradle plugins to Artifactory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have the **maven-publish** plugin on, the **java-gradle-plugin** already declares publications for you, so you can remove [this explicit publications block](https://github.com/AlainODea/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/blob/d7a21432311c2d07a29a590638eed71fe3ef50a5/build.gradle.kts#L74-L80) from your build:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```

You can then reference all automatically created publications in [your artifactory publish defaults block](https://github.com/AlainODea/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/blob/d7a21432311c2d07a29a590638eed71fe3ef50a5/build.gradle.kts#L88) as follows:

```
invokeMethod("publications", publishing.publications.names.toTypedArray())
```

Why not just **publishing.publications.names**?:

- publishing.publications.names has type SortedSet<String>
- ArtifactoryTask.publications() expects an Object... which is an Object[] really.
- Calling ArtifactoryTask.publications() with a SortedSet<String> will attempt to add the entire set as if it is a single publication
- So you need toTypedArray() to make it a Object[] so that the varargs call works

Here's the complete, corrected artifactory block:

```
artifactory {
    setProperty("contextUrl", "https://artifactory.verafin.com/artifactory")
    publish(delegateClosureOf<PublisherConfig> {
        repository(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            setProperty("repoKey", "libs-release-local-maven")
        })
        defaults(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            invokeMethod("publications", publishing.publications.names.toTypedArray())
        })
    })
}
```

Here's a complete adaptation of your build.gradle.kts solving the problem:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.PublisherConfig

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.9.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
}

group = "com.example.hello"
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("helloPlugin") {
            id = "com.example.hello"
            implementationClass = "com.example.HelloPlugin"
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.junit:junit-bom:5.3.2")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit:junit-bom:latest.release")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testImplementation("com.natpryce:hamkrest:1.7.0.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
}

tasks {
    withType<JavaExec> {
        jvmArgs = listOf("-noverify", "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1")
    }

    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        val javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion
        kotlinOptions {
            apiVersion = "1.3"
            javaParameters = true
            jvmTarget = javaVersion
            languageVersion = "1.3"
        }
    }

    withType<Test> {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish(delegateClosureOf<PublisherConfig> {
        repository(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            setProperty("repoKey", "libs-release-local-maven")
        })
        defaults(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
            invokeMethod("publications", publishing.publications.names.toTypedArray())
        })
    })
}
```

Here's a log showing the successful deployment of the plugin artifact to Artifactory:

```
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/com/example/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/com/example/hello/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local-maven/com/example/hello/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin/0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.example.hello.gradle.plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/webapp/builds/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/1234567890123
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 4.19 of the build-info-extractor-gradle plugin, there's an `ALL_PUBLICATIONS` constant that can be used:

```
artifactory {
  publish {
    contextUrl = 'https://url.com/artifactory'
    repository {
      // repoKey, etc. here
    }
    defaults {
      publications 'ALL_PUBLICATIONS'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For those who's looking for more info about 'ALL_PUBLICATIONS' - check the official JFrog plugin documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

After giving a lot of time into this I finally got the working code for deploying custom plugin to private artifactory

```html
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = ‘username’
            password = ‘password’
        }

        defaults {
            publications("pluginMaven")
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle plugin dependencies

```html
plugins {
    id "java-gradle-plugin"
    id "org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl" version "2.1.4"
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.27.1"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.10'
    id "maven-publish"
    id "com.gradle.plugin-publish" version "0.18.0"
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```html
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Must use pluginMaven for the publications

Here is my complete build.Gradle file

```html
plugins {
    id "java-gradle-plugin"
    id "org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl" version "2.1.4"
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.27.1"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.10'
    id "maven-publish"
    id "com.gradle.plugin-publish" version "0.18.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        simplePlugin {
            id = 'com.example.plugin'
            displayName = 'Code Check Plugin'
            description = 'This plugin will be used for checking code convention'
            implementationClass = 'com.example.plugin.CodeCheckPlugin'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
}

tasks.create("checkJavaVersion").doLast {
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.current()
    if (!javaVersion.isJava8()) {
        throw new GradleException(
                "The plugin must be published under Java 1.8 but $javaVersion is found"
        )
    }
}


artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = 'user_name'
            password = 'password'
        }

        defaults {
            publications("pluginMaven")
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```