# publishing gradle plugin to artifactory with jfrog/artifactory 5.x

Tags: kotlin, gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I try to publish a gradle plugin to my artifactory it does publish the .jar, .pom and .module but not the com.company.build.ktlint.gradle.plugin
here is the code i tried it like in the example of gradle but somehow it is missing something :( also the other question asked about this did not helped.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("java-gradle-plugin")
    alias(libs.plugins.com.jfrog.artifactory)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin.dsl)
    id("maven-publish")
}

val latestTag: String? by project

val versionName = latestTag ?: "SNAPSHOT"
val publishGroupId = "com.company.build"
val publishArtifactId = "ktlint"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(gradleApi())
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("ktlintPlugin") {
            id = "com.company.build.ktlint"
            implementationClass = "com.company.build.ktlint.KtlintPlugin"
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("ktlint") {
            groupId = publishGroupId
            artifactId = publishArtifactId
            version = versionName

            from(components["java"])

            pom {
                name.set("Ktlint plugin")
                description.set("This plugin provides an easy way to use ktlint for code style deviations")
                scm {
                    connection.set("scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket/and/ktlint.git")
                    developerConnection.set("scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket/and/ktlint.git")
                    tag.set(versionName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    if (!hasProperty("artifactory_user") && !hasProperty("artifactory_password")) return@artifactory
    setContextUrl("https://artifactory01")
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "gradle-local"
            username = project.findProperty("artifactory_user") as String
            password = project.findProperty("artifactory_password") as String
        }
        defaults {
            publications("mavenJava")
        }
    }
}
```

job output is this here:

```
> Task :ktlint:extractModuleInfo
[pool-1-thread-1] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory01/artifactory/gradle-local/com/company/build/ktlint/1.0.1_2/ktlint-1.0.1_2.jar
[pool-1-thread-1] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory01/artifactory/gradle-local/com/company/build/ktlint/1.0.1_2/ktlint-1.0.1_2.module
[pool-1-thread-1] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory01/artifactory/gradle-local/com/company/build/ktlint/1.0.1_2/ktlint-1.0.1_2.pom
> Task :artifactoryDeploy
```

and i find them in artifactory

i tried to Put it inside `afterEvaluate` did nothing also using ALL_PUBLICATIONS
I tried also this solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757070/how-do-i-publish-gradle-plugins-to-artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com) but did not work i get this here as an error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Action<PublisherConfig!>!
Found: Closure<Unit>
```